# Converting C++ Builder code to C# .NET (TComponent, TOjbect, TList, etc.)

Tags: c#, c++, c++builder, vcl

Where can I find API documentation for `TComponent`, `TObject`, `TList`, etc.? I am converting some C++ code that was written using C++ builder into C#. I'm having trouble finding related documentation for these classes in order to find a C# equivalent.

Comment: I believe it it is version 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [official online reference](http://docs.codegear.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/idx.html). The link is directly to the index - just look up types and functions there as needed.